# Sinatra seemingly expecting that class should be a part of current framework

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra, and have this code for the setup:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyServer < Sinatra::Base
  def initialize()
    puts 'initialize'
    super(app)

    @my_thing = Something.new
  end

  run! if app_file == $0
end

class Something
  def initialize
    @a_thing
  end
end
```

When I run `ruby test.rb`, I get this error:

> Unexpected error while processing request: uninitialized constant MyServer::Something

That suggests that it's expecting Something to be a class within MyServer's domain (I only started Ruby recently so don't know the correct terms). Moving the `Something` class to inside `MyServer` class, it works.

This is fine for a class written inside this file, but I want to add a class from a relative file as the property. I've tried moving the `require_relative` statement to inside the class, but that hasn't worked.

Is there a way I can tell it this isn't a part of the current framework, or another way that I should be handling the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `run!`, the server is started immediately, and the rest of the script is only evaluated when the server is finished. At the point you call `run!` in your script the `Something` class hasn’t been defined yet, so isn’t available to the server.

That line doesn’t necessarily need to be inside the `MyServer` class, you can move it to the end of the file, but you will need to specify the receivers:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyServer < Sinatra::Base
  # Define your app...
end

# Your helper object...
class Something
  #...
end

# Now start the server as the last thing:
MyServer.run! if MyServer.app_file == $0
```

Sinatra itself [uses an `at_exit` block to start the server](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.7/lib/sinatra/main.rb#L25) in classic mode, so that the server is only started after everything has been loaded.